# How to sum the values in the table by month?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with field:

```
id - primary key 
values - some double values
dt = datetime
```

This table has a lot of records. Each entry in the table corresponds to a single day, which is recorded in dt.

How do I get the sum of the values by month counting from some date?

For example, I want to get the values from the specified day. I just send a request to the table

```
SELECT `values` FROM `some_table` WHERE `dt` >= '2014-11-21 21:26:00' LIMIT 7
```

Here I have to sum the values on days for each month.

How to make such a request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`EXTRACT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract). Then you can group on the year and month and get the sum of values for them.

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt) as month, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt) as year, 
    SUM(values) as total
FROM 
    some_table
GROUP BY 
    month,
    year
ORDER BY 
    year DESC, 
    month DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the year and the month from a date column using [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function, and then you have to use a [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) query:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(`dt`, '%Y-%m') AS year_month,
  SUM(values) AS total
FROM
  some_table
WHERE
  `dt` >= '2014-11-21 21:26:00'
GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT(`dt`, '%Y-%m')
```